# Why do multiple `.appendTo` calls on a newly created jQuery element only append it once?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I’m trying to add five new list items to the end of the unordered list `#myList`. My approach was to do the following:

```js
const $newItem = $("<li>New Item</li>");
const $ul = $("#myList");

for(let i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
  $newItem.appendTo($ul);
}
```

However this doesn’t work as it only inserts one list item into the list, not five.

In R. Murphy’s *jQuery Fundamentals* (in the Manipulation exercises in the [jQuery Basics](https://web.archive.org/web/20110328084400/https://jqfundamentals.com/book/index.html#chapter-3) section), the solution provided by the author is very close to mine, the only difference being she doesn’t store the new list item in a variable, but rather uses an HTML string:

```js
const $ul = $("#myList");

for(let i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
  $("<li>List item " + i + "</li>").appendTo($ul);
}
```

It seems like my approach should work also, so I’m struggling to understand why it doesn’t. Why is this?

Comment: Closely related: [How to append one jQuery element already in the DOM to another element?](/q/6364633/4642212).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach creates a single `li` element outside of the loop and tries to append the same thing to the `ul` five times. But since you hold a reference to a single `li`, each time you append it, it actually removes it from where it is and re-adds it there..

In the solution the `li` is created inside the loop so it is a new `li` element each iteration.

You could change your own to use the [`.clone()` <sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/clone) method

```
for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
    $newItem.clone().appendTo($ul);
};
```

This way it will create a copy and you then add that to the `ul`.

Comment: This answer covers a lot of explanation of this behavior, but it’s worth mentioning that a node (every element is a node and jQuery objects work the same way) can only be attached to the DOM _once_, at most. Any attempt to insert an already attached node will just _move_ the node elsewhere, i.e. detach the node and attach it at the new location. This is also documented in [jQuery’s documentation on `.appendTo`](//api.jquery.com/appendTo) (and others): _“If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)”_.

Answer (score 1):

you can also repalce the pointer

```
$newItem
```

into the loop

example:

```
var $ul = $('#myList');
for (var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
var $newItem = $('<li>New Item</li>');
$newItem.appendTo($ul);
};
```